# How can I reduce the LVM space and assigned that reduced space to existing partition?

Tags: debian, filesystems, partition, lvm

Had this condition, I really need a space in /dev/vda1, how can I reduce the size of my LVM in /dev/mapper/vg-data-lv_data by 10G and assign those 10G of space to my /dev/vda1 partition ?

If it's possible, can I do it without any machine rebooting ?

[image: Partition]

Edit, lsblk output :

[image]

Comment: print the output of `lsblk`

Comment: @erTugRul Hi, I already add the output

Comment: You cannot do what you want. Because `vda1` is 40G non-lvm partition and cannot be further extended. No matter how many other `vd*` disks you have. Only solution is take backup and then create again LVM partition for `/`.

Comment: It's not possible to take un-allocated space on one disk and add it to another; other than using LVM, of course. You can probably move some of the files on your root filesystem to logical volumes on the other disk. But, in the best scenario you'd use up all the space on vdb1 and free up ~17 GB on your vda1. On the other hand, if you get a larger disk and put LVM on it, you'd be able to migrate most of your system to the new disk without rebooting. Then, when you have scheduled maintenance you can migrate the rest of it over and get rid of those "tiny" disks :)

Comment: You don't tell where your needs comes from, but maybe symlinking a directory of `/` into another under `/data` may help you in the short term.

Comment: @erTugRul ah yeah I get it now, it sure is not a solution that I want but I'm learning from it, thanks sir

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Sure I'll planning some time on maintenance and epand those size, thank you sir

Comment: @FerencWágner This is interesting, I'll do it tonight thanks a lot sir!